# Soot android-jars error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, soot

I am trying to analyze android apk's using Soot. However, I get an an error saying `invalid option: android-jars` along with a `CompilationDeathException: Option parse error`. Is this due to the wrong path of android jars or soot(2.5.0)?

To launch soot, I am using the script found here: http://www.abartel.net/dexpler/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The command-line option -android-jars was not included in soot-2.5. Use the latest nightly version instead.